# How can I Switch Select language widget from JOIN LIFRESHLIFE FAMILY NOW button in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKUUa.png)

I am having difficulty in switching the places of the Select language widget from the JOIN LIFRESHLIFE FAMILY NOW button in WordPress. Guys, I am a newbie in the field of WordPress Development. Can someone please give me insights from basic? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Please provide additional info on how this menu was created. If it was created using code, please post the code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

You can switch places by mean of some plugins. Weglot is one of the most wonderful plugins for griding the buttons and widgets. You need to look it up.

Comment: Weglot plugin seems to be a translation plugin which doesn't address the question of styling/positioning the widget or menu items. Please provide additional info on how it can be used.